# nsoftware SSNMP V8 .Net Send Multicast Trap

Tags: c#, .net, networking, snmp, multicast

Does anyone know if it's possible to send a trap on a multicast IP address with an snmp agent (from nsoftware ssnmp library) ?
Off course I've read the documentation and search on nsoftware web site, but I didn't find anything about that.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it works on XP but not on seven and I think it's a multicast socket issue as I read in this post : [UDP multicast using winsock API differences between XP and Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524946/udp-multicast-using-winsock-api-differences-between-xp-and-vista)

I've try the 9th version of the librairy and it works on Windows 7 too :)

Comment: For the moment it's only a beta version : http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/ssnmp/features.aspx

Comment: I just saw this answer. For what it's worth I just tried V8 on Windows 7 with 225.0.0.1 and didn't have any problems. In any case if you'd like to submit a support issue we can continue investigating that way if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send a trap to a broadcast address? You can do that by doing something like this:

```
  Snmpagent agent = new Snmpagent();
  agent.SendTrap("255.255.255.255", "coldstart");
```

You specify the IP address as a parameter to SendTrap so you can set anything you'd like there (like the broadcast address above).

Comment: Thanks but in my question i've talk about Multicast. For exemple sending trap to 225.0.0.1

Comment: I see. There's no restriction in the component as to what IP address you can set, you can set anything you want there so that shouldn't really be a problem. What happens when you set 225.0.0.1? I work at nsoftware, so feel free to send an email to support@nsoftware.com if you'd rather continue this conversation that way.